# Running python scripts using Windows AT command line prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, scheduler, administration, at-job

The question is: How should exactly look the AT command to schedule a one-time task to be executed by python. Here is what I tried:

```
at 20.00 "cmd python e:/path/to/file/script.py"
at 20.00 c:/Python27/python.exe e:/path/to/file/script.py
```

Neither is working, please advice. Command line example is required, can't use Scheduler Wizard on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/kb/313565)

> time: Use this parameter to specify the time when the task is to run. Time is specified as hours:minutes based on the 24-hour clock. For example, 0:00 represents midnight and 20:30 represents 8:30 P.M.

So the time format you're using `20.00` is incorrect, and should be `20:00`.

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you so much! Sorry for the stupid question tho